# Access geolocation with Selenium WebDriver, Chrome, and macOS

Tags: java, macos, selenium-webdriver, geolocation, github-actions

I want to run a test to access the geolocation coordinates with Selenium WebDriver (version 4.0.0-rc-1):

https://github.com/bonigarcia/selenium-webdriver-java/blob/master/selenium-webdriver-junit5/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/webdriver/jupiter/ch5/caps/geolocation/GeolocationChromeJupiterTest.java

I run this test on GitHub Actions, and it test works nice on `ubuntu-latest` (Ubuntu 20.04), `windows-latest` (Windows Server 2019), but not in `macos-latest` (macOS 10.15). It seems Chrome in Mac cannot access the geolocation data:

[image]

Does anybody know if it is possible to achieve it?

Comment: Make sure that geolocation is enable in browser. BTW selenium uses by default a temporary browser profile which can have different settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I post here just in case it helps someone. In the macOS preferences, we need to enable location services for Chrome (System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Location Services), as follows:

[image]

After that, the test can access the location coordinates.